# Parse heap dump information from linux command [jcmd]

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, jcmd

I am not so good with Linux commands & Can someone please tell me what would be an efficient way to gather total(33521664K) & used(22917322K) values from this command result

```
> jcmd 27047 GC.heap_info 
27047:
 garbage-first heap   total 33521664K, used 22917322K [0x00007XXX, 0x00007XXX, 0x00007XX)
  region size 8192K, 1307 young (10706944K), 9 survivors (73728K)
 Metaspace       used 154942K, capacity 169384K, committed 210432K, reserved 210944K
```

I have thought of using ***grep*** with "garbage-first" which will give me the line of information I want & doing ***awk***.
Most likely there could a better way of grabing those values.

Answer (score 0):

If your format is always "total" followed by digits and "K", then grep will do:

```
grep -o 'total [0-9]\+K' | grep -o '[0-9]*'
grep -o 'used [0-9]\+K' | grep -o '[0-9]*'
```

The first grep matches total/used followed by the kilobytes and outputs only the match. The second grep extracts the number from the first match